# Как обрезать текст больше n строк?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Есть у меня тег . Максимальное к-во строк для вывода должно равняться 3-м. Ширина, допустим 250 px. Так вот, есть какая-то возможность с помощью php или js/jquery обрезать символы, которые уже увеличивают отметку в 3 строки? Или единый вариант, посчитать к-во символов, которые помещаются в эти 3 строки, а все остальные обрезать?

```css
h3{
  width:250px;
}
```

```html
<h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores accusantium aut impedit mollitia repudiandae soluta minima, sit veniam tempora nesciunt magnam laborum, cupiditate eius, animi ex vel incidunt ratione reprehenderit.</h3>
```

Comment: Что такое строка? Строка это некое количество букв до символа переноса строки "\n". Что такое символ? символ это графическое изображение чего либо в данном случае буква. Какой ширины символ? А мы не знаем бывает куча шрифтов, и у самих символов ширина разная... А сколько в данный моменты символов в строке и какого их ширина у клиента мы тоже не знаем. Вывод: Надо менять концепцию. Лимитировать количеством слов к примеру.

Comment: @Naumov да и слова могут быть разной длины... В общем, поставленная задача в том концепте, в котором сейчас она есть не имеет места быть решенной?

Comment: @Naumov накину немножко: есть ещё символы нулевой длины, комбинированные симолы, другие символы переноса строки...

Comment: Решение то имеет, но трудозатраты на реализацию такой задачи не сопоставимы с реальной пользой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**html**:
Вам необходимо просто узнать высоту строки. Соответственно, высоту элемента сделать равной высоте трёх строчек, спрятав оставшееся содержимое свойством **overflow**:

```css
#pops{width:250px;border:1px solid green;height:55px;overflow-y:hidden}
#pops:hover{height:auto}
```

```html
<div id="pops">
Изготовители ювелирных украшений – это художники, чья фантазия постоянно ломает рамки, поставленные технологическими ограничениями. Прогресс пришел на помощь ювелирам, экономя временные и финансовые ресурсы, позволяя расширить границы доступного в создании шедевров. Создавать неповторимые изделия быстро и недорого, забыв о слове «невозможно», не приобретая дополнительные материалы и инструменты для изготовления моделей? Сегодня это возможно благодаря технологии 3-D печати, которая произвела настоящую революцию в ювелирном деле. 
</div>
```

**php** Урезайте строку на количество символов в ряд х3 (при фиксированной ширине родителя):

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci aspernatur atque dignissimos earum eos esse harum ipsam iste maiores";
<?=substr($str, 0, 96) . " ...";?>
```

Comment: я не уточнил в вопросе самом. А в конце (видимой области) как сделать 3 точки вместо последних 3 букв?

Comment: Вы реализуете блок "читать далее"?

Comment: нет, просто нужно обрезать текст, который превышает 3 строки и в конце поставить 3 точки вместо 3-х символов последних. Без всплываек, без ничего.

Comment: текстовые блоки выводите с помощью php или наполняете вручную?

Comment: Вывожу с помощью php

Answer (score 2):

#### Javascript:

*Внаглую в цикле режем слово за словом и проверяем влезаем ли в scrollBox.*

```js
function ellipsize(id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var list = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
    while(el.scrollHeight > el.offsetHeight) {
        list.pop();
        el.innerHTML = list.join(' ') + '...';
     }
}
ellipsize('text');
```

```css
#text {
  line-height: 1.4;
  height: 4.2em; /*3 line-height*/
  width: 400px; /*optional*/
}
```

```html
<h2 id="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores accusantium aut impedit mollitia repudiandae soluta minima, sit veniam tempora nesciunt magnam laborum, cupiditate eius, animi ex vel incidunt ratione reprehenderit.</h2>
```

#### Чисто-CSS решение.

*Работает, к сожалению, только в `Webkit`.*

```css
h2 {
  display: block;
  display: -webkit-box;
  max-width: 400px;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores accusantium aut impedit mollitia repudiandae soluta minima, sit veniam tempora nesciunt magnam laborum, cupiditate eius, animi ex vel incidunt ratione reprehenderit.</h2>
```

#### Для одной строки:

```css
h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores accusantium aut impedit mollitia repudiandae soluta minima, sit veniam tempora nesciunt magnam laborum, cupiditate eius, animi ex vel incidunt ratione reprehenderit.</h2>
```